# Como hacer que el label del eje X en ChartJs se vean completas y ademas horizontales

Tags: php, javascript, chart.js

tengo un problema al mostrar las labels horizontales en el chartjs, intente cambiando el tamaño de la letra y obviamente lo reduce, pero lo que quiero realmente es que aparte de que el tamaño se reduzca, también el label encaje en dos renglones de ser necesario. Y no únicamente uno como es por defecto (y como se ve en la imagen).

Como pueden ver en la imagen, deberian de haber 9 labels, pero solo esta mostrando el titulo de tres, ya logre rotarlo, porque me gusta mas horizontal, pero aun necesito reducir la letra y/o acomodarlo para que encaje en dos o tres renglones

La opcion que accede a los ejes horizontales es

```
xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                fontSize: 10,
                maxRotation: 0 // angle in degrees
              }
            }],
```

Este es el codigo completo:

```
<script>

    var data = {
            labels: ["Cuidado Del Cabello", "Listerine - Aceite", "Cremas Corporales - Estuches", "Resto", "Jabon Adulto - Crema Liq. Baby", "Jabon Baby", "Carefree - Bano Liquido", "OB - Toallitas", "Stayfree - Desitin"],
            datasets: [

                    {"label" : "Cuota marzo","backgroundColor" :"#5DA5DA","data" : [195872263, 221779339, 161250805, 141306654, 175639549, 147123174, 251369895, 54415438, 199509073, ]},{"label" : "Venta marzo","backgroundColor" :"#FAA43A","data" : [12588888, 300000000, 1919191, 0, 91919113, 0, 9411191, 54000000, 0, ]}

            ]
        }

    var ctx = $("#grafico1").get(0).getContext("2d");       

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    maxRotation: 0 // angle in degrees
                  }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            var formmatedvalue=formatMoneda(value);
                            return formmatedvalue;
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            animation: {
                animateScale: true
            },
            tooltips: {
                // enabled: false,
                intersect: 'false',
                mode: 'index',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
                        var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                        var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
                        var formmatedvalue=formatMoneda(tooltipData);
                        return formmatedvalue;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data: data,
    });
</script>
```

Gracias

[image: Grafico ChartJs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navegando encontré la forma de hacerlo, Se debe pasar un sub array con el label (soportado despues de chartjs 2.x)

`labels: [["etiqueta", "mas", "larga", "de", "todas"], "etiqueta 2"],`

Para esto encontre la siguiente función la cual se pasa en el callback

```
function formatLabel(str, maxwidth){
var sections = [];
var words = str.split(" ");
var temp = "";

words.forEach(function(item, index){
    if(temp.length > 0)
    {
        var concat = temp + ' ' + item;

        if(concat.length > maxwidth){
            sections.push(temp);
            temp = "";
        }
        else{
            if(index == (words.length-1))
            {
                sections.push(concat);
                return;
            }
            else{
                temp = concat;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    if(index == (words.length-1))
    {
        sections.push(item);
        return;
    }

    if(item.length < maxwidth) {
        temp = item;
    }
    else {
        sections.push(item);
    }

});

return sections;
}
```

Aqui el codigo de como se debe de pasar el label para que sea formateada

```
xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        fontSize: 10,
        fontStyle: \'inherit\',
        maxRotation: 0,
        minRotation: 0,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
            var formmatedvalue=formatLabel(value, 15);
            return formmatedvalue;
        }
    }
}],
```